# Error with show variable in data viewer for jupyter notebook

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the recent VS Code release, they added this feature to view the active variables in the Jupyter Notebook and also, view the values in the variable with Data Viewer.

However, every time I am trying to view the values in Data Viewer, VS Code is throwing error below. It says that the reason is that the object of data type is Int64 and not string, but I am sure that should not be the reason to not show the variable. Anyone facing similar issues. I tried with a simple data frame and it's working fine.

```
Error: Failure during variable extraction:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-eae5f1f55b35> in <module>
     97 
     98     # Transform this back into a string
---> 99     print(_VSCODE_json.dumps(_VSCODE_targetVariable))
    100     del _VSCODE_targetVariable
    101 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py in dumps(obj, skipkeys, ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators, default, sort_keys, **kw)
    229         cls is None and indent is None and separators is None and
    230         default is None and not sort_keys and not kw):
--> 231         return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
    232     if cls is None:
    233         cls = JSONEncoder

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py in encode(self, o)
    197         # exceptions aren't as detailed.  The list call should be roughly
    198         # equivalent to the PySequence_Fast that ''.join() would do.
--> 199         chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
    200         if not isinstance(chunks, (list, tuple)):
    201             chunks = list(chunks)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py in iterencode(self, o, _one_shot)
    255                 self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
    256                 self.skipkeys, _one_shot)
--> 257         return _iterencode(o, 0)
    258 
    259 def _make_iterencode(markers, _default, _encoder, _indent, _floatstr,

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py in default(self, o)
    177 
    178         """
--> 179         raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
    180                         f'is not JSON serializable')
    181 

TypeError: Object of type int64 is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Hi  @VP, thanks for posting your question, I also ran into the same problem, have you come up with a solution yet by any chance? Cheers